# Calendar Overlay: Is there a way to make the calendars in view also color coded?

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I am trying to create a master calendar to view multiple team's time off calendars. I currently have it setup so that it is color coded per team on the master calendar but I want to be able to click on a specific team's calendar (under 'Calendars in View' in the upper left) and then view that team's calendar where it is then color coded based on the kind of time off such as vacation, paid time off, or work from home. Currently when I select one of the team's calendars I just get it all in one color. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you missed ahoff's comment on the answer by James Grizzle, you can create overlaid views on existing views in a calendar. So if you have a calendar with overlaid views/calendars for Time Off, Meetings, and Events, and you want the events in the Time Off view to be color coded, you can create a new view to filter the events shown only in the Time Off by type, for example a filter for only Time Off event marked as Vacation, and another for events marked as PTO. Then you do a normal calendar overlay while in the Time Off view.

Reference this solution (http://summit7systems.com/color-code-calendar-events-in-sharepoint/), but apply the steps in each existing view rather than on the main calendar.

The basic gist of the solution is to create a column with a choice option to specify the event type (PTO, Unpaid Time Off, Vacation). Then create a filtered view for each event type and use those views to create colored overlays. Then modify the main calendar overlay/view to filter out the duplicate events created by overlaying a view.

Answer (score 4):

You can setup calendar overlays for the team specific calendars.  You just need to create a view for each calendar and then link to that view in the calendar overlay for the team specific calendar.

The below text is copied from [this blog](https://davidlozzi.com/2012/01/26/color-code-your-sharepoint-calendar/).

---

Quick steps to create a view

In the ribbon, click the Calendar tab, then click Create View

On the bottom half of the page, select existing view Calendar

Name it accordingly.

Scroll down to the Filter and specify your filter

Click OK

Continue these same steps to create each view. At the end, you should have a few views. Check out each view and ensure you’re seeing unique values in each. If you see the same value in more than one, it will appear more than once (in each color) in your color coded calendar.

Once your views are made, go to your site home page and browse to your calendar page. This will ensure we’re on the default page that your users will also access.

Now let’s bring it all together

In the ribbon, click the Calendar tab

Click Calendars Overlay

Click New Calendar

Name it, preferably the same name as your view

Select your color

Ensure the correct URL is specified and click Resolve

Select your Calendar list

Select your View

Check Always Show

Click OK

Do this for each view and then click OK to return.

Now you have a pretty color coded calendar! You’ll also see a legend on the left, which helps define the colors for your users.

Comment: I appreciate the help! But unfortunately that just gets me to where I am. After looking at it what I want is so that the different views that I have created can be color coded when I switch to them. So far I have it color coded when they are all in one but when I switch to a view for a specific team then it is one solid color but I want that color coded as well.

Comment: I misunderstood, sorry.  I thought you had separate team site calendars (like a separate list for each team).

Comment: All good. I'm not even sure if there is much of a solution to what I want haha. Not to mention I was kind of confusing with my wording. Might just have to have multiple calendars.

Comment: You should still be able to use overlaid fviews in a calendar to show separate colored events in each view. You can basically do a view-ception and create additional views based on the events in each view (hopefully that makes sense). Then you just do overlays for each view in the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to color code based on category.  I would paste the step by step instructions here but it would be a very long answer.  You would likely have to add additional checking to determine if you were looking at a top level calendar or specific view.  In the case of the top level calendar, you would ignore the JavaScript and let the Calendar Overlay handle the color coding.

[SharePoint 2013: Calendar - Colorize Event Categories](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22431.sharepoint-2013-calendar-colorize-event-categories.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This might perhaps help you with doing the layers and assigning different colours - It helped me set up a team calendar at my work place!

Hope it helps in some way!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdMwwSIEZE8

Answer (score 0):

Ryjogoff,

YES YOU CAN, I know exactly what you mean and yes you can.  You are asking if once you click one of the calendar views on the left...that may be ORANGE...you want the calendar to display orange and not the default "SharePoint blue".  Just add a Content Editor webpart to the top of that view page and override that default blue with:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-acal-item {
background-color:#WHATEVERCOLORYOUWANT!important;}
}
</style>
```

Comment: for whater reason this page deleted the <style type="text/css"></style> tag around my code above